# Can we use SOA architecture in RESTful web services?

Tags: web-services, rest, soa

While implementing REST web services, is it possible to use SOA concepts?

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand the nature of your question but it is actually the other way around because `SOA` is more a design pattern that evolves around breaking down modules of a system into its own independent service, where service could (or could not) be a REST web service. If that is your question, then yes, an SOA system can use REST web services.

Answer (score 1):

Having a bunch of web services or rest services or COrba services does not make it SOA. SOA is a architectural design pattern that can be applied regardless of the technology used. Like Leo said it is a design pattern

Answer (score 1):

SOA is a software design paradigm. Its a high level concept for designing a software . A design paradigm or pattern is a collection of best practices that are used by many programmer over the years and make them as a standard.
While REST is an architectural design pattern that is used to defined or orchestrate a web application. 
Now for designing a SOA you can use any of underlying technology i.e REST or SOAP. Both are different in nature and architecture wise. Any IT organization uses SOA for exposing its business process as a business services that are well orchestrated as IT services over IT infrastructure. All these business services are loosely coupled , platform independent and interoperable.  So just to wrap up all SOA is a software design paradigm that is used to orchestrate the business services and these business services are loosely coupled and interoperable. To implements SOA and your business services you can use any architectural pattern or technology like REST or SOAP.

Answer (score 0):

Question should be reversed:

> Can we use RESTful web services in SOA architecture

To which the answer is yes you can.

However, I assume you actually mean

> Can we use RESTful web services in SOA architecture, as the primary
>   means of communication between services.

Some (myself included) would argue that services consuming REST on other services for anything other than POST operations violate the second tenet of SOA which states that *Services are autonomous*.